# confused over positive padding and negative margin

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I have the following code that's doing what I want but I'm confused over what and why the positive padding-bottom and negative margin-bottom are needed.  Could someone explain?

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
}

.left,
.right {
  padding-bottom: 8000px;
  margin-bottom: -8000px;
}

.clr {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    float right div dynamic content here<br /> dynamic row<br /> dynamic row<br /> dynamic row<br /> dynamic row<br /> dynamic row<br /> dynamic row<br /> dynamic row<br /> dynamic row<br /> dynamic row<br /> dynamic row<br />
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like a visual trick to make the left column appear as if it's the same height as the right column, but it really isn't. At least, not as far as the content area is concerned. I hope you're not using this in a new project.

Comment: A much better alternative to full height sidebars using modern technology would be [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).  CSS Tricks also has [good information on the subject](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: flexbox look like the way to go!  Thanks